# kotlin google maps running custom Coroutines

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

How to run a custom Coroutine when using google maps. I have a function that returns the current location but I want to call this function without having to press a button or move the map. In summary I'm trying to create a custom Coroutine to call getMyCurrentLocation() every 500ms to 1000ms, exact timing is not so important. Should be similar to setOnCameraMoveListener() just run without having to have a user triggered event. I have tried examples for custom threads and coroutines but I don't get the data that I get from calling setOnCameraMoveListener(). Brand new to kotlin.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMapsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    getMyCurrentLocation()

}



override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    var longLatHolder112 = LatLng(0.0,0.0)
    mMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(this, R.raw.style_json))
    val locationMyHome = LatLng(22.869559, 10.915800)
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(locationMyHome))
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(16.0f)
    longLatHolder112 = getMyCurrentLocation()
    val blueDot = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bluemarker)
    val mo = MarkerOptions()
        .position(longLatHolder112)
        .title("Current Location Marker")
        .snippet("me")
        .icon(blueDot)
        .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
    val myMarker : Marker = mMap.addMarker(mo)

    myMarker.setPosition(longLatHolder112)

    mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener {
        longLatHolder112 = getMyCurrentLocation()
        myMarker.setPosition(longLatHolder112)

    }

    mMap.setOnCameraMoveCanceledListener {
    }

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener {
        longLatHolder112 = getMyCurrentLocation()
        myMarker.setPosition(longLatHolder112)
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you use `.requestLocationUpdates` from LocationProvider class for that?

Comment: Could you Please explain more as I'm still having trouble with this.

Comment: You have an instance of `fusedLocationProviderClient` just use `.requestLocationUpdates` on this object and pass in  a callback to get notified of position changes

Comment: so I already have:         fusedLocationProviderClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            locationRequest,locationCallback,Looper.myLooper(), how can I read the updates in the onMapReady function?

Comment: > how can I read the updates in the onMapReady function?

You don't. Instead you read the updates from locationCallback and use a map object to update the map

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I ended up getting the location to update.